# How to find IPA user creation date?

Tags: redhat, freeipa

Command `ipa user-show $user -all` doesn't show what I have described in title.
Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't appear to be a way to obtain the account creation date using the API (which is what the `ipa` CLI tool uses), but it is available directly via LDAP as an [operational attribute](https://directory.fedoraproject.org/docs/389ds/howto/howto-operationalattributes.html) called `createTimestamp`.

```
ldapsearch -b 'cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=SUB,dc=DOM' [options] "uid=$user" createTimestamp

dn: uid=$user,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=SUB,dc=DOM
createTimestamp: YYYYmmddHHMMSSZ
```